# How can I get the child pages of multiple page ID's in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Apologies if this was already asked, but I DID search for it and found nothing. I'm trying to output the child pages of more than one page ID in the same list and also *only* output 6 of those pages in an assorted way. In other words, I want to get the child pages of more than one page and mix the results in the output.
Right now I'm using:

`<?php
    $nbpages = 6;
    $pages = wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_column=post_name&child_of=1041');
    $pages_arr = explode("\n", $pages);
    for($i=0;$i<$nbpages;$i++){
    echo $pages_arr[$i];
    }
?>`

Which is fine for getting the child pages of *one* ID, but I can't figure out how to add an array to get more than one, then mix the results. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should switch over to using `WP_Query`, which allows to specify a `post_parent__in` parameter. This parameter accepts an array of page or post IDs. Note: you need to run WP 3.6 or higher for this.

```
$so26932595_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_type' => array( 'page' ),
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'order' => 'none',
    'post_parent__in' => array( 1043, 1045, 1047, 1049, 1591 )
) );

while ( $so26932595_query->have_posts() ) :
    $so26932595_query->the_post();
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query